# What is right way to use cyrillic in python lxml library

Tags: python, xml, lxml, cyrillic

I try to generate .xml files fith cyrillic symbols within. But result is unexpected. What is the simplest way to avoid this result?
Example:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.Element('пример')

print(etree.tostring(root))
```

What I get is:

```
b'<&#1087;&#1088;&#1080;&#1084;&#1077;&#1088;/>'
```

Istead of:

```
b'<пример/>'
```

Comment: I can't try to make tag name in cyrillic - its only for example. Instead of - I try to places cyrillic symbols between tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`etree.tostring()` without additional arguments outputs ASCII-only data as a `bytes` object. You could use [`etree.tounicode()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tounicode):

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> root = etree.Element('пример')
>>> print(etree.tostring(root))
b'<&#1087;&#1088;&#1080;&#1084;&#1077;&#1088;/>'
>>> print(etree.tounicode(root))
<пример/>
```

or specify a codec with the [`encoding` argument](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring); you'd still get bytes however, so the output would need to be decoded again:

```
>>> print(etree.tostring(root, encoding='utf8'))
b'<\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80/>'
>>> print(etree.tostring(root, encoding='utf8').decode('utf8'))
<пример/>
```

Setting the encoding to `unicode` gives you the same output `tounicode()` produces, and is the preferred spelling:

```
>>> print(etree.tostring(root, encoding='unicode'))
<пример/>
```